# Delimit the modulus of an unknown modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose we have a function $f(n) = 1$ when $n \equiv x mod M$ and $0$ otherwise, but I don't know $M$.

Also suppose I know $f = 0$ for a subset of $q$ natural numbers.

How I can delimit $M$? That is,  $M > m1$.

There are exist a known algorithm fo such a problem?

Any clue to investigate further is welcome.

Edit: $x$ is fixed and unknown.

Edit2: One trivial algorithm is just test all possible values of M from 2 to $q$. I look for a more optimal algorithm because $M$ and $q$ can be big ($10^5$).

Comment: Is $\ x\ $ fixed ?

Comment: Yes, but is also unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, $f=0$ for $k$ consecutive natural numbers. Then, we can conclude $M>k$ because
of $M$ consecutive integers , there must be one congruent to $x$ modulo $M$

Comment: Yes, but the set of natural number can be not consecutive. That's the problem.

Comment: Then, you have to find the greatest block of positive integers contained in the given set. And depending on the set, you may be able to rule out more moduli.

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts/Avenues:

- Check if their sum and/or difference are in the set, if they are, then their remainders don't add and/or subtract to x.
- Take their gcd. if they are same remainder mod M, their gcd will be a factor of M.

etc.